# How can using combinations of binding seals to trap various types of demons be discouraged?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems

Sealing magic is a specialized form of magic that is used to bind and trap supernatural creatures. A mage who specializes in this area would normally use seals against demons, either to contain them within certain objects or to prevent them from crossing a barrier. These seals would block the demon from escaping, permanently keeping it encased within an area or realm designed to contain it. However, there is no multi-purpose seal that is geared for all demons, as the amount of time, expense, and complexity needed to produce such a seal would be astronomical. A seal is specifically designed to match a demon's level of power, turning that very power against the demon when it tries to attack or push through it. A specialist must know what type of demon it is dealing with and discover its attributes and statistics. Once that information is obtained, the specialist must place it within a category and construct a seal based on those parameters.

There are three categories from which to choose from. Type A seals are for the high class demons. These are the most ancient and powerful of demons who can level entire armies and cities. Type B seals are for mid-class demons that are average in power. While they are mid-range fighters and not all that powerful, they are still dangerous and can cause significant damage on their own. Type Cn seals are for the weakest demons that are usually the smallest. They are more of a nuisance individually and can be dispatched easily, but in large groups they can become major annoyance and even cause much harm in large groups. As their is no single seal that can accomplish all of these parameters, the obvious solution would be to use them in tandem with each other. This would be done by layering them one on top of the other, with one picking up the slack where the others fail. This solution would prevent any demon from breaking the set combination of seals.

What would prevent mages from using this outside the box thinking and force them to construct a single seal based on categories?

Comment: What is a "seal" in this context? I realize the first answer fills that in for you, but that was not (part of) the question, and seems an important detail to answer this.

Comment: A is fallen angel very powerful but will feel insulted when they found out you try to capture them like any other demons and then things could get personal ;D

Answer (score 25):

**Opposed Polarities.**

[image]

A seal works like a big magnet. Suppose a castle is full of Demons from the Positive (Magnetic) Energy plane. Stick the negative pole of a big enough magnet through the castle walls, and all the demons get stuck to the negative end.

Likewise, if a fortress is full of demons from the Negative (Magnetic) Energy plane, they can all be sealed using the positive pole of a big magnet.

So why not combine both types of magnet to form a Universal Sealer? Well, you already know the answer -- it's because the two poles will cancel each other out and give you a useless seal.

This works if there are two types of demons, but you have three types. In that case, we have something more like color charge than electric charge:

[image]

Rather than positive and negative sealers, there are now 6 types of sealers: red, blue, green, antired, antiblue, and antigreen. The colors correspond to the three types of demons, so let's call them sealers of type $A,B,C,\overline A,\overline B,\overline C$.

A sealer of type $\overline A$ attracts demons of type $A$ and they get stuck to it. 'Sealers' of type $A$  are the opposite -- they repel demons of type $A$. They are Wards rather than Seals, and stop demons of type $A$ from entering an area. Likewise the other two colors will seal and ward the corresponding types of demons.

You do not mention type $\overline A$ ,$\overline B$ ,$\overline C$ demons. Perhaps they correspond to the three types of angels. Perhaps they are simply not in the story. Perhaps this is why no one has ever thought about anti-A and anti-B seals?

The reason you cannot use two types of seals at once is they interfere according to the addition rules:

$$A+B = \overline C \qquad A+C = \overline B \qquad B+C = \overline A$$

$$\overline A+\overline B =  C \qquad \overline A+\overline C =  B \qquad \overline B+\overline C =  A$$

and of course seals of type $A$ and $\overline A$ cancel each other out just like with the positive and negative magnets.

The exact rules are unimportant. The takeaway is that if you put two colors at once, they combine such to form a different one of the six basic colors. As a result, you cannot slap all three $A,B,C$ types of seals on the same object and expect them to work. The rules say the $A$ and $B$ seals combine to form a $\overline C$ seal, which cancels with the $C$ to leave you with nothing!

You can, of course, create three nested containers, each with a different seal. But this won't work either, as the closer together the containers are, the faster they leak into each other and cancel out. To compensate, you could make the second container much larger than the first, and the third even larger than that. This is no  easy feat, because it means the third seal must be very powerful to ward such a large area.

Answer (score 12):

They interact.

You can not just build a seal wall that will keep the demon in.  The seal must actively react to its actions.

Consequently, one seal treats another as if it were a demon to be contained.  The effect is destructive, and since they are as mechanical and unthinking as a waterwheel, they can not learn to distinguish.

Comment: Glad there's people of the same mind. I would conpare it to having 2 anti virus programs on a computer that start attacking each other.

Answer (score 5):

You mention that developing a universal seal to trap all entities would be prohibitively expensive, but I greatly doubt that some bright young magus hasn't at least considered layering as an alternative. So why didn't it work?

First, let's define what a seal is. Given the mention of trapping demons in objects, I'm going to assume that a seal is - at least in part - a magical construct that is anchored to the object in some way. Let's imagine that the seal is akin to a complex rune inscribed on the surface of the object, and also an equally complex magical structure that attaches to (or originates from) the rune and permeates the object. The magical structure is the prison that binds the demon while the rune is the control and power source for that magical structure.

So what we have here is a fairly standard enchanting problem, with all of the normal enchanting issues. There are a ton of different reasons to limit the number of enchantments, glyphs, wards and so on that you can place on a single object:

#### Material Capacity

Each material has a limit of how much magic it can hold, and only really expensive materials could potentially hold the magic for more than one Seal. Perhaps the materials that work best for each class of Seal are incompatible with the other classes. Certain ceramics work best for Type-1 Seals, metals for Type-2 and rare (and expensive) gems for Type-3.

#### Material Compatibility

Using the wrong material makes the spell fail, and the compatible materials for each of the classes of Seal are incompatible with the others.

#### Object Structure

Spells have to take up space, and the wrong shape of object just won't fit the spell properly. And since the shape of the object helps hold the shape of the spell, just dropping the spell into a big block of mithral or something won't work. And of course all Seals are different shapes.

#### Interference

This is my favorite options: when spells overlap they interact and interfere with each other. Unpredictable results occur, with extremely bad things happening often enough to make this not just a bad idea but one that nobody (well, nobody who isn't actually trying to destroy the world) would ever consider.

(OK, mostly it just all fizzles out. But do you want to risk tearing open a portal to the Chaos Realm when it all goes wrong? Nah, me neither. Bob would though. Don't trust Bob.)

This can also stop the creation of composite objects that have the different classes of Seals in separate pieces that, when joined, create the effect of a single object with all three Seals. The spells interfere so strongly that the presense of a Type-3 Seal will destabilize any lesser seal within a few inches.

---

I could (and often do) go on, but ultimately the solution I'm proposing is this: your magic system simply doesn't allow it to happen. Each Seal is incompatible with all others in some way, so bringing them together in a single object is just not going to work. Even if your Seals are done as inscribed magic circles on simple stone, any attempt to combine them is doomed to failure.

If you want a general-purpose Seal you're going to have to bite the bullet and develop one from first principles. Or maybe talk the gods into doing the hard work, they've probably got a vested interest in stopping Demons.

Comment: Similar possibility: layering more than one seal makes the whole structure incredibly fragile, unstable and unbalanced. It is like building a house of cards with different sized cards. Yes, it is actually possible. And no, it won't work for longer than 5 seconds. More specifically, it will work flawlessly until somebody breathes out in the vicinity of the stacked seals. Then the whole thing would crash down like a house of cards it is.

Comment: "Using multiple seals in tandem results in Undefined Behavior."

Comment: @coppereyecat at least when I hit UB in my programs it doesn't generally result in fireworks or, you know, world-wrecking holes in space. Generally :P

Answer (score 4):

**The seals are sentient entities.**

The seal is not some inert carving.  The seal itself is an entity, or a part of an entity.  The types of seals correspond with specific types of entity and one of these (if the term "one" applies to such entities) is then charged with containing the demon, or an angel, or an ifrit, or whatever work that the seal is supposed to do.

To a seal entity, the entities corresponding with the different seals are just more supernatural things to be contained.  The different types of seal entities are not friends or even similar.  Entities corresponding to different seal types are viewed more or less on par with the demons and angels.  They will be contained, or not contained if too strong.  There is no cooperation.

Answer (score 4):

**Seals *can* overlap, but doing so kills the caster**

It's just a popular misconception that seals cannot overlap. But the truth is that there's no rule of magic that prevents it, just as there is no rule of magic that strictly prevents the construction of a "universal" seal.

The problem is that each seal releases magical energy into its immediate environment (which is part of how the seal does its job). When two seals overlap, the combined effect destroys the mind and then the spirit of any mortal in the vicinity. The caster, necessarily being present, is inevitably killed.

The lucky ones die quickly.

As a general rule, people do not engage in activities that reliably lead to their own gruesome demise. They also can't study or experiment with such phenomena.

Answer (score 4):

Using the wrong seal on a demon actually increases the demon's power, enough to overwhelm proper seal. Seals are actually very precise to their given demon (why there are hundreds, maybe thousands of different seals) and mismatching the demon and its seal will dramatically increase the power of the demon, making it significantly more difficult to defeat and subsequently seal. Curiously, there is actually a seal to use for demons with increased power, but it must match with both the demon and seal. Mismatching layered seals will create an exponentially complex final seal, which is both infuriating to decode (nigh impossible if you don't know every previous seal) and prohibitively expensive due to the seal creation process.

Comment: I feel like the next question is "Do I get better loot for killing a demon after I deliberately mismatched seals?"

Comment: @MichaelS Despite the ease in creating Seal Demons, there is very little research in the actual field of these creatures as they are illegal to intentionally create and are quickly and effectively dealt with by authorities when they do appear. The few available pictures and videos of Seal Demons show creatures of greater size than their original forms with peculiar growths forming on along the spine. It is theorized that a Seal Demon would be worth at least twice as much dead and four times as much alive compared to their normal forms.

Answer (score 2):

A seal is basically an inscription made on top of a flat surface. It can be composed of a pigment (paint/ink/whatever), but can also be incised into a material (chiseled into stone or a fingerpaint smear on top of a big paint spill). The materials are also important, for some seals stone won't work, or only certain types of stone work. Or paint won't work.

The shape/geometry of a seal is of course very important, and must be inscribed to within some very small tolerance. Certain seals may also have minimum and maximum sizes (beyond those imposed by their practicality). The shapes aren't always purely circular, but they do encompass the full 360° of a circle. (Exceptions do occur, some seals are linear and block doorways.) Generally, no other human/sapient inscriptions can overlap a seal... it essentially changes the seal itself to something else.

If the sizes themselves are incompatible, such that the inscription of one seal would overlap another, then it's quite clear why that won't work. Nor can one cheat and move the second seal to another flat surface, one no longer properly traps a demon. Other problems of geometry account for the majority of seal-doubling issues... magic that relies on four cardinal corners is broken when a second seal essentially adds another corner to the mix. Or a seal that must be chiseled in stone no longer provides a flat surface upon which to paint a painted seal.

Additional problems can occur with the materials themselves. A seal that must be painted with ochre will contaminate one that must be poured in white sand. Colors themselves are important, but difficult to determine the specifics for when the people from your story don't even have proper theories of optics/color/radiation.

In this way, you can occasionally allow for doubled seals when it serves the purpose of your story, but restrict them almost arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

### Power source problems

The Seals cannot intersect without destroying each other, but you could nest them like [Russian dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll). With the demon as the innermost doll.

Unfortunately, only the innermost Seal will be able to draw power from the demon.

Even if mismatched, the demon will use some time to break out of this Seal.
At that point, the outside Seals will have faded away from lack of power.

**Alternative**: Only the outermost Seal will be able to draw power from ambient mana.  The inside Seals will fade away.